# Hong Kong visa for Chinese passport holder living abroad?

Tags: hong-kong, chinese-citizens

I'm getting sponsored by a company in HK to work over there. I would like to bring with me my father (60+ years old) who **has a Chinese passport and is living in Italy.**

What are the solutions for him to come live with me **while I work in HK for several years probably**, since I won't have Hong Kong permanent residency.

Answer (score 1):

If he has permanent residency in Italy then he can apply for entry permits directly with the Hong Kong Immigration Department. An Exit-Entry permit is not required, as those are only issued to current mainland residents.

For procedures, see https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/overseas-chinese-entry-arrangement.html

You can sponsor him for visit visas which could allow him to stay for up to 90 days at one time.

However it's not likely he'll be eligible to live with you in Hong Kong on a long-term basis. Depending on your situation, you may want to consider a cross-border living arrangement where he lives in Shenzhen or other nearby areas, at which time he will become a mainland resident, and may need to apply for an Exit-Entry permit (but recognized overseas Chinese often has different rules/procedures).

Comment: hi zhantongz,  my father is not permanent resdency in italy. The HKID told me it's possible to apply for  Prolonged Visitor Visa  but they can't tell how long the visa last because they have to study my case. Do you know how long does this visa last maximum ? How many time can it be extended and under what condition?

Comment: @EdouardShin A temporary residence permit (> 1 year) may also be accepted by the embassy. Usually the visa is issued for 3 or 6 months but I have no knowledge or experience for the applicability/renewability of such visa for parents.

Answer (score 1):

Only residents with HKPR can sponsor resident visas for their parents. You might be able, as a non-PR, to help him get a visit visa, and help him extend it at HK ImmD, but that is not publicly codified. ImmD decides on a case by case.

Having him settle down in Shenzhen until you get PR, and possibly live with him (I used to live in SZ while working in HK) either full-time or on and off could be the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

He has to use his HK passport and apply for a visa like everyone else. It's unlikely he will get approved for the duration but you can try. I am sure you are aware of the various passports and identity cards mainland Chinese citizens have for traveling to the SARs and Taiwan (Chinese Taipei), whichever part you think is right.

Comment: Only Chinese citizens who are Hong Kong permanent residents can get HKSAR passports. I am assuming that the OP's father is not a Hong Kong permanent resident (or else the OP wouldn't be asking this question), and has a regular PRC passport.

Comment: @user102008 The question states he has a Chinese passport so he is a mainland citizen, mainland citizens have multiple passports, 1 for international travel, one for travelling to the SARS HK and Macau and a third one for Taiwan, so he would need to use his Majnland china passport for HK so to say since it’s different from his normal mainland China passport and apply for entry permit,

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to the [Exit-Entry Permit for Travelling to and from Hong Kong and Macau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit-Entry_Permit_for_Travelling_to_and_from_Hong_Kong_and_Macau) (aka "Two-way Permit") or [People's Republic of China Permit for Proceeding to Hong Kong and Macao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Republic_of_China_Permit_for_Proceeding_to_Hong_Kong_and_Macao) (aka "One-way Permit")? These travel documents are not "passports".

Comment: @user102008 well that’s semantics but yes, but we all refer to them as passports in our daily life

Comment: @MattDouhan hi, my dad doesn't' have the chinese residency card, he only have the chinese passport (mainland). Can he apply for visit visa ? how long does it last ? can it be renewed at each expiration without any condition ?

Comment: @EdouardShin no he cannot, if he is a mainland citizen he needs that HK card to apply for entry permit

Comment: how long does the exit entry visa last ? does it have an expiration ? can it be renewed indefinitely ?

Comment: @EdouardShin not indefinitely no, see it as a passport with valid dates, once you have it, then you can apply for entry permission which is electronically added to it, normally 2 or 3 entries